# Нужно ли отделять придаточное (→)?

Tags: запятые, спп

> У нас с ним уговор был: будут спрашивать мой телефон – никому не
>   давать. Кому нужно, тот его и так знает. Поэтому, как только ко мне
>   обращались за «телефончиком», я показывала на Диму и капризно
>   выговаривала: вот у него спросите. Никогда не давал. Никому. Кремень!
>   И люди разные были. Всякие. **Иногда жалко было даже кого он
>   отшивал!** Зато как смешно потом про это рассказывал!

Comment: А точно без ***тех*** можно? Я другого не понимаю: зачем отделено ***поэтому**?*

Comment: "Поэтому" я собственноручно отделила: начало придаточного (главное - поэтому я показывала). А без "тех" точно можно - мы же стремимся максимально точно передать разговорную речь.

Comment: Согласен, что в разговорной речи такое вполне может быть, поэтому — да, надо передавать речь точно! :) А вот насчёт запятой я почти полностью согласен теперь — действительно, можно выбросить придаточное и тогда "поэтому" относится к главному. Но нельзя ли всё-таки отнести его и к придаточному (как другой вариант)? Можно я задам вопрос с вашей фразой, чтобы особенно ничего не сочинять?

Comment: Тёмочка, конечно можно: спрашивай!

Comment: Кстати, как вы считаете, перед "и тогда" это ошибка без запятой или она не нужна? Можно ко второй части после тире применить обычное расчленение ССП?

Comment: У нас есть и передняя часть до тире (в пользу непостановки запятой), и "действительно" как общий член (про запас). )))

Comment: Спасибо! Да, что "действительно" общий член, мне тоже казалось, и что он не в пользу запятой говорит.))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Иногда жалко было даже кого он отшивал!*

Такие случаи факультативны.

> Если при союзном слове, образующем придаточную часть, имеется частица,
>   то постановка запятой перед ней факультативна: Я не помню, что именно;
>   Он затрудняется сказать, что ещё; Эту цитату можно будет найти, я даже
>   помню примерно где.

http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_34.htm#ppp_2

У нас как раз такой случай - при союзном слове КОГО есть частица ДАЖЕ. Я бы не ставила запятую, потому что мне видится здесь превращение придаточного в член предложения - дополнение: *Иногда жалко было даже кого он отшивал!* Чаще такое бывает с придаточными, заменяющими обстоятельство, тогда придаточное превращается в слитное сочетание, становится фразеологизмом: *Вчерашний день прошёл как обычно*. Наш же случай переходный.