# "Пару флягов на прощание" - читатель поймёт без словаря?

Tags: заимствования

> А встали – словно очнулись и принялись за историческое фехтование –
>   похватали какие-то палки. Ну и знаете там – испанская школа,
>   французская школа. И пару флягов на прощание.

Кстати, ничего, что "пару"? не "пара"?

Comment: Непосвящённому покажется, что речь о фляжке мужского рода, лучше обмениваться "батманами" или "туше".

Comment: Можно заменить одну букву: Фляг (рондат фляг) — то же, что и Фляк. Пара флягов = паре фляков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фляги - это перевороты назад? Если это научный текст, надо бы объяснить, в художественном тексте разъяснения как-то не смотрятся, надо бы сделать нижнюю сноску на словарь, не все же поймут.

```
  Кстати, ничего, что "пару"? не "пара"?
```

Стиль разговорный, можно оправдать неполнотой конструкции

> А встали – словно очнулись и принялись за историческое фехтование –
>   похватали какие-то палки. Ну и знаете там – испанская школа,
>   французская школа. И (показали) пару флягов на прощание.

Но чтобы вопросов не было, лучше всё же поставить в именительном падеже, оформив как номинативное предложение.

Comment: Люсенька, спасибо! А сюда https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453102/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%e2%86%92?noredirect=1#comment463557_453102 ?